# Magento 1 to 2 theme migration

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, migration

I was wondering if there are any good guides for migrating a magento 1 theme to 2 as the magento documentation doesn't really give me an idea on how to do it. I am a back end developer!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no migration path from a 1.x theme to a 2.x theme. The frontend templates and code are vastly different. Your time would be better spent developing a new 2.x theme customised with the look and style of your 1.x theme, or adapting a commercially available theme to fit your requirements.

There is plenty of [official Magento documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) on frontend theme development.

In my experience the theme will be the least of your problems, if your 1.x shop is highly customised you will also need to look at developing your own custom modules to implememt all of your 1.x features into the 2.x store. As a backend developer this will quite likely keep you busy!